# Empty spaces and no alignment in table

Tags: tables, tabularx, makecell

I am trying to create a table. This is the code I am using and I am getting this output. As you can see there are weird cell alignments and I can't explain the blank spaces in the bottom part either. Help is appreciated.

[image]

```
\begin{frame}{Ergebnisse}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{0.9\columnwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
         \textbf{Architektur}                       & \textbf{Model}    & \textbf{Lhasa-Ü-Tsang}     & \textbf{Changdu-Kham}  & \textbf{Amdo Pastoral} \\ \hline
         Dialekt-spezfisch                          &                   & 28.83             & 62.56         & 17.6          \\ \hline
         \makecell{WaveNet-CTC \\ ohne Dialekt ID}  &                   & 29.55             & 62.83         & 33.52         \\ \hline
         \makecell{WaveNet-CTC \\ mit Dialekt ID}   & DialektID-Sprache & 32.84             & 68.58         & 33            \\ \cline{2-5}
                                                    & Sprache-DialektID & 26.8              & 64.03         & 30.79         \\ \hline 
         \makecell{Attention- \\ WaveNet-CTC}       & DialektID-Sprache & 52.19             & 65.24         & 50.22         \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                                    & Sprache-DialektID & 55.16             & 67.78         & 55.23         \\ \hline
         \makeCell{WaveNet- \\ Attention-CTC}       & DialektID-Sprache & 21.44             & 60.16         & 20.46         \\ \cline{2-5}
                                                    & Sprache-DialektID & 23.79             & 62.96         & 24.15         \\ \hline
                                        
    \end{tabular}
}
\caption{SER(\%) des Multitask Modells für Spracherkennung}
\end{table}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: What result do you actually want? Do you have a sketch of the desired output?

Comment: Change `\makeCell` to `\makecell` -- and don't ignore LaTeX's error messages.

Comment: @Mico Thanks that solved the issue with the blank spaces. Now I only want "DialektID-Sprache" and "Sprache-DialektID" cells to be the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you give the whole table a more open "look", mainly by omitting all vertical lines and retaining few, but well-spaced, horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,multirow,makecell}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{SER (\%) des Multitask-Modells für Spracherkennung}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L{1.45} l *{3}{C{0.85}} @{}}
   \toprule
   Architektur & Modell & Lhasa-Ü-Tsang & Changdu-Kham & Amdo Pastoral \\ 
   \midrule
   Dialekt-spezfisch          & & 28.83 & 62.56 & 17.60 \\ \addlinespace
   \makecell[l]{WaveNet-CTC\\ohne Dialekt ID}  
                              & & 29.55 & 62.83 & 33.52 \\ \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{WaveNet-CTC\\mit Dialekt ID}}   
            & DialektID-Sprache & 32.84 & 68.58 & 33.00 \\
            & Sprache-DialektID & 26.80 & 64.03 & 30.79 \\ \addlinespace 
   \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{Attention-\\WaveNet-CTC}}    
            & DialektID-Sprache & 52.19 & 65.24 & 50.22 \\ 
            & Sprache-DialektID & 55.16 & 67.78 & 55.23 \\ \addlinespace
   \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell[l]{WaveNet-\\Attention-CTC}}    
            & DialektID-Sprache & 21.44 & 60.16 & 20.46 \\
            & Sprache-DialektID & 23.79 & 62.96 & 24.15 \\ 
   \bottomrule                             
\end{tabularx}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```